# Installing different environments inside torch

Tags: pytorch, virtual-environment

I was wondering if I could install other sub-environments for different deep learning projects inside the torch environment I just installed. Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

I have just installed the PyTorch environment for GPU.

Comment: What do you mean by "torch environment"?